# Combining RTCMultiConnection v3 and meteor

Tags: meteor, webrtc

How do I get the new v3 of https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection to work with Meteor. It seems to need Socket.io....

I had v2 working by trading the session ids through the server myself, is that possible again to keep my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can run v3 on [a separate port `9001`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection#set-different-socket-url) or similar; and your meteor application (or PHP/ASPX pages) can use/access that port internally. E.g.

```
// in your meteor page or PHP page
connection.socketURL = 'https://yourdomain.com:9001/';
```

Now you can take [any HTML demo or code from v3](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/demos) and it will work in your meteor application.

v3 also supports [Firebase/PubNub](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection#firebase) however socket.io is preferred.

Comment: But how do you install and use the signalling server you describe in the meteor app. I saw you created a library but no real Documentation for meteor. Very confused

Comment: Also is the main difference between v3 and v2 the signalling server? I know some events changed, but how big is the v2 and v3 difference?

Comment: I've to learn about meteor. That's why I didn't provide any demo myself yet. V3 is  more reliable comparing V2; and this is the only difference. BTW, yep, you're right, V3 is MORE_Reliable out of its Socket.io Signaling implementation.